# Calculate vertical edge coordinates(locations) in splitted & shuffled image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Assume that you have a digital image. You crop that image into 6 pieces vertically. After, you shuffled these pieces and rearrenge these pieces(sub images) randomly. So, you obtain a image like below.

[image: ss]

I want to reconstruct the original image like a puzzle. First, we need to calcualte right points on X axis which sub images merged. For example, in the 100th pixel(X-axis), two subsample merged. I have to parse these points to regain sub-images. How can I do that?  The image splitted vertically, Is sobel filter on X axis help me to find sharp transition? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting directed graph problem. In each slice the last column has a distance error to the first column. After you build the graph you just need to find the head, and walk along the minimum cost path.
I've sketched a script you coult start from start from:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cut_thr = 0.19 # magic number , but kind of arbitrary as if you add a cut, you just make your graph bigger
im = cv2.imread(r'example.png').astype(np.float32)/255 #read image
im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
dx=np.abs(np.diff(im,axis=1)) #x difference
dx = np.max(dx,axis=2) #max on all color channels
dx=np.median(dx,axis=0) #max on y axis
plt.plot(dx)
```

[image]

```
cuts = np.r_[0,np.where(dx>cut_thr)[0]+1,im.shape[1]] #inclusive borders
cuts = [im[:,cuts[i]:cuts[i+1]] for i in range(len(cuts)-1)]
n = len(cuts)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,n)
for a,c in zip(ax,cuts):
    a.imshow(c, aspect='auto')
    a.axis('off')
```

[image]

```
  d = np.ones((n,n))*np.nan # directed connectivity 
    for y in range(n):
        for x in range(y+1,n):
            d[y][x]=np.median(np.abs(cuts[y][:,-1]-cuts[x][:,0]))
            d[x][y]=np.median(np.abs(cuts[x][:,-1]-cuts[y][:,0]))
    src = np.arange(n)
    dst=np.nanargmin(d,axis=1) # the dest of source is the one with the lowest error
    indx=np.where(d==np.nanmin(d))[0][-1] #head, where to begin
    im = cuts[indx]
    for i in range(n-1):
        indx=dst[src[indx]]
        im = np.concatenate([im,cuts[indx]],axis=1)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(im, aspect='equal')
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer! I understand your approch for slicing sub images but I do not understand how you compare & sort the sub images. Also, reconstruction part(3rd code block) acceptable for this case but does not work for other examples. Do you have any suggestion to compare sub images? Do you extracting and comparing left&right edges would work?

Comment: Each sub image is a node in a graph, and the edges are the difference between the last column of the source image to the first column of the destination image (this is why d(x,y)!=d(y,x)). After you build the full graph matrix (what marked as d), you just need to find a path involving all the nodes with the smallest weights.

Comment: Once you have all the weights it is the traveling salesman problem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: I got it! Your code does not work for other examples even I changed threshold. The sorting algorithm does not work for other images. So, I changed the algorithm. It first looks for leftsmost sub image, after that it predict right of the each sub image.