# Python: Fit 2 puzzle tiles togheter to create one image

Tags: python, image-processing, puzzle, orb

If have a project where I need to solve puzzles with tiles. I need to solve 2x2, 2x3, 3x3, 4x4 and 5x5 tile puzzles. And the difficult part is fitting 2 puzzles pieces togheter. I already managed to cut the tiles out of the image, rotate them until they are set straight, and remove the background so that I get 4 images out of a 2x2 puzzle tile image.

But now I don't really find a way to fit these puzzles togheter. I wrote a function that rotates 2 images until all sides have aligned once with each other:

[image]

Until I have this:

[image]

So for every rotation I need to check if the rgb pixels on the right side of the first picture, matches the pixels on the left side of the second picture. I tried something with ORB but this is not going to work out I think:

[image]

I was thinking about taking multiple rgb pixels and matching them on the images. And the closest matches get the highest score, and based on the highest over score we get the best match.

Does somebody have a suggestion, tip or code I could use?
(And yes I know I need to adjust my cropping method because I indeed lost some of my pixels on the sides I think, thats why the image looks a bit weird when I put it togheter.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: feature matching is pointless here. -- you need to line both tiles up in every possible way, then compare the edges (edge pixels) as they are aligned, and calculate a score. sum of absolute/squared differences could be a good metric.

Comment: have a look at the link below (similar problem)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081396/calculate-vertical-edge-coordinateslocations-in-splitted-shuffled-image